# Как перезаписать первые 256 байт в файле на Golang?

Tags: файлы, golang, ос

Как правильно перезаписать первые 256 байт в файле? (Перезапись=замена).
Файл размером в несколько гигабайт, нужно перезаписать только первые 256 байт без смещения, не затрагивая 257 байт и так далее. Как это можно сделать на Golang?

Answer (score 0):

Всё довольно просто:

```golang
b := []byte{/* Your bytes here. */}
f, err := os.OpenFile(filePath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
check.Err(err)

defer f.Close()

_, err = f.Write(b)
check.Err(err)

err = f.Sync()
check.Err(err)
```

В [документации `io.Writer`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) ясно написано, что:

> (…) Write must return a non-nil error if it returns n < len(p). (…)

То есть, если `Write` не вернул ошибки, весь `b` записан, а если вернул ошибку — смотрите её и обрабатывайте в соответствии с требованиями.